# What is the HTML entity for Woman Pedestrian? ‍♀️

Tags: html, special-characters, emoji, html-entities, html-encode

I know that the HTML entity for Man Walking as follows:

```
&#x1f6b6;
```

This renders fine in browser as:

```
‍♂️
```

However, what is the HTML entity for a Woman Walking?

```
‍♀️
```

Comment: `&#x1F6B6;&#x200d;&#x2640;`, per emojipedia. possibly with a fe0f appended but it seems to work without.

Comment: Thanks Roddy! If you want to post as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Does it make any difference whether the `&#xFE0F;` is appended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/woman-walking/), you can get the 🚶‍♀ emoji by combining "the Pedestrian and Female Sign emojis".

The pedestrian emoji (🚶) is `&#x1F6B6;`, as you noted in your post. The Female symbol (♀) is `&#x2640;`. To combine them, you use a zero-width joiner (`&#x200d;`) and, properly, terminate the sequence using `&#xFE0F;`. (note that certain systems, like SO, don't require the terminal. That particular [invisible codepoint](https://emojipedia.org/variation-selector-16/) indicates that the previous character sequence should be displayed as an emoji.)

So the resulting sequence is: `&#x1F6B6;&#x200d;&#x2640;&#xFE0F;`, which renders as: 🚶‍♀️

(Note that this "sequencing" of emojis is also how you render skin tones and other similar customizations.)

Comment: Nitpick: `200d` is "zero-width _joiner_". "zero-width _space_" is a completely different thing (`200b`).

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Amadan - Whoops yes, sorry. I was looking at the 200B (space) earlier and totally conflated them in my answer -- sorry. Luckily user Jack Bashford was on the ball and fixed the answer for us. Thank you for pointing it out!